# Add a mysql subquery to select data from yesterday

Tags: php, mysql

I've a delivery system with the following mysql SELECT:

```
SELECT tb_pedido.*,tb_usuarios.nome,tb_usuarios.email,tb_usuarios.cpfcnpj, DATE_FORMAT(data_hora, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM tb_pedido,tb_usuarios where tb_pedido.id_usuario=tb_usuarios.id_usuario and (status=2 OR status=4) and DATE(data_hora) = CURDATE() order by id_pedido desc
```

It selects the orders form today with a specific status. What I want to do is to add a sub query to return all results from yesterday with status 8.

I guess the following subquery would work but I don't know how to add it to the current query:

```
DATE_ADD(DATE(data_hora), INTERVAL -1 day) AND status=8
```

Anyone please?

Comment: Try using `DATE_ADD()` instead of `CURDATE()`. An example for tomorrow's date would be: `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`. More information can be found at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add.

Comment: @CaleW.Vernon Thanks for your help,  I'm using DATE_ADD to get yesterday date. It worked but I don't know how to use they both together into 1 query.

Comment: Consider providing proper create and insert statements and a desired result

Comment: "What I want to do is to add a sub query to return all results from yesterday with status 8". I thought it was pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
SELECT tb_pedido.*,tb_usuarios.nome,tb_usuarios.email,tb_usuarios.cpfcnpj, DATE_FORMAT(data_hora, '%Y-%m-%d') 
FROM tb_pedido,tb_usuarios 

WHERE 
(tb_pedido.id_usuario=tb_usuarios.id_usuario 
and (status=2 OR status=4) 
and DATE(data_hora) = CURDATE())
OR
(DATE(data_hora) = DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE()))
and status=8)

order by id_pedido desc
```

Comment: Got the following error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GETDATE()))
and status=8)

order by id_pedido desc' at line 9

Comment: Try CURDATE() rather than GETDATE()?

Comment: I had to group the results but it worked! Thanks